# How to open crystal report page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 10.2 version. I have applied paging, and when I open the 3rd page, the following error is raised:

> Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\StatReportNewV {94692B41-40A2-4F6A-9551-110BA7D78A37}.rpt: The request could not be submitted for background processing.

Please help how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly generic error in Crystal Reports, but you can try the following:

1. Make sure you're on the latest service pack
2. Crystal Reports can create temporary files; make sure there aren't an excessive amount of files in this folder.
3. Run the same query in your database and see if you have any NULL records coming back, which may be causing an exception in your report.

If the report always crashes on the 3rd page, I suspect there is some data on that third page that you're not handling properly, either because of a function, formatting, invalid data type, something along those lines.